# try to run this progrmmer (console) In python but show me error

Tags: python, function

I am beginner in python. I want to run this programmer in console but it's show me error what wrong in it.

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...             print (a, end=' ')
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print (a, end=' ')
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my actual program, which i want to run:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...         print(a, end=' ')
...         a, b = b, a+b
...     print()
>>> fib(1000)
```

Comment: It looks like you're running Python 3 code in Python 2.  Either install Python 3, or find some tutorials/sample code that uses Python 2.

Comment: You could also use `from __future__ import print_function` to make this particular example run. There may be other Python 3.x specific code in the example that isn't backported, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to run a Python3 code in Python2. The [Python2 `print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) is a keyword and just prints what's given, whereas the [Python3 `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function with some additional parameters. [Python3 `print` was backported to Python2 and you can made it available using `from __future__ import print_function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...         print(a, end=' ')
...         a, b = b, a+b
...     print()
... 
>>> fib(5)
0 1 1 2 3
```

In plain Python2 it would look like this:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     while a < n:
...         print a, ' '
...         a, b = b, a + b
...     print
... 
>>> fib(5)
0  
1  
1  
2  
3
```

Unfortunately, Python2 `print` writes a newline at the end if you don't print a dot (`print 1, 'something', '.'`). See [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space) for ways to go around it.

Or you could just store the results and then concatenate and print them at once, e.g.:

```
>>> def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     results = []
...     while a < n:
...         result.append(a)
...         a, b = b, a + b
...     print ' '.join([str(r) for r in results])
... 
>>> fib(5)
0 1 1 2 3
```

Comment: If i want to create a programmer in python 2 then how we can do ?